# spring 4.0.6 Haibernate 4.3.6.Final AOP

Tags: spring, hibernate, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-orm

I am trying to have an application with Spring, Hibernate and AOP.

No errors occurred but AOP @Before method didnt work.

Can someone guide to an example of Spring + Hibernate + AOP example.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Did you `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have added @EnableAspectJAutoProxy and @Configuration also.